# What function does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{(1-2n)n!^24^n}\frac{x^n}{y^{2n}}$ correspond to?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, closed-form

I have the following Taylor series, and although it looks familiar, I cannot figure out which function it corresponds to!  Does anyone recognize this Taylor series?

$$1+\frac{x}{2y^2} - \frac{x^2}{8y^4} + \frac{x^3}{16y^6}+\frac{5x^4}{128y^8}+.... = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{(1-2n)n!^24^n}\frac{x^n}{y^{2n}}$$

Thank you!

Comment: The numbers in the first $3$ denominators, $~\displaystyle 2^1, 2^3, 2^4$, don't seem to follow a clear pattern.  Please specify another $5$ or $6$ terms, so that the pattern of the numbers in the denominators is clarified.

Comment: Sorry about that!  I added the series.

Comment: @NickMatteo Thanks, my blindness.  I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good series to know offhand is

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4t}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {2n \choose n}t^n $$

which almost gets us the series we desire with $t = -\frac{x}{4y^2}$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{4y^2}}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {2n \choose n}\left(-\frac{x}{4y^2}\right)^n $$

except for the offending term $1-2n$ in the denominator. However a small adjustment to the original series with $t = -z^{-2}$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{z^2}}} = \frac{|z|}{\sqrt{z^2+4}}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty {2n \choose n}(-1)^nz^{-2n}$$

gives us the series we want via integration

$$\sqrt{z^2+4}\operatorname{sgn}(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {2n \choose n}\frac{z^{1-2n}}{1-2n} \implies \frac{\sqrt{z^2+4}}{|z|} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {2n \choose n}\frac{z^{-2n}}{1-2n}$$

by substituting $z= \frac{2y}{\sqrt{x}}$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {2n \choose n}\frac{1}{1-2n}\left(-\frac{x}{4y^2}\right)^n = \boxed{\frac{\sqrt{y^2+x}}{|y|}=\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{y^2}}}$$